# How to get rid of the Bang & Olufsen panel on HP laptop?

Tags: windows, laptop, drivers, hp-laptop

On my HP Windows 10 laptop the following Bang & Olufsen panel appears at the top of certain audio apps, e.g. Skype:

[image: Bang & Olufsen AppFollower]

How can I get rid of that?

Comment: If you download and run Process Explorer - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer -  can you drag the cross-hair icon over it to identify a process?  From there you can find the auto-start location of that process I would suspect.

Comment: More than likely it is part of the sound driver that HP provided, if you can find and install a generic driver for your sound chip it should eliminate this annoyance. HP did the same thing for Beats Audio years back. Also check control panel>Programs and features list for software related to Olufsen and remove it before installing the generic sound driver.

Comment: This also applies to HP laptops without Bang & Olufsen audio (same exact popup with the HP logo instead of the B&O one).

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Click on it and press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>.

Comment: This might be a short answer but sometimes the short ones actually work. If the author could include a source or the OP can confirm if this works I'm happy to let this one slide.

Comment: This is the universal close window keyboard shortcut on Windows so even if it doesn't work it's a legitimate attempt to answer the question.

Comment: Golden. Thanks. a million upvotes, if I could.

Comment: it works.. (OP)

Comment: tbh I was expecting this daemon-like toolbar to pop right back up (since killing process from Tray & Task Manager wasn't doing shit) and to my delight, it worked. Hopefully forever (or at least until I power cycle the device), such an incredible nuisance.

Comment: lmao nevermind it came back just now after ~90 mins of using the laptop. Still a better solution than nothing, will try out the executable renaming below next.

Answer (score 26):

A coworker informed me that certain versions of the B&O control panel have an option to disable it.  This would be the preferred approach:

> [image: Partial screenshot of HP B&O control panel on certain laptop models displaying a "Show sound controls during VoIP calls" toggle switch.]

If (like me) your version does not have such an option, [HP says](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Software-and-How-To-Questions/Remove-Bang-amp-Olufsen-Pop-up/td-p/6767651) that you can <strike>delete</strike> rename the following executable:

```
C:\Program Files\CONEXANT\Flow\AppFollower.exe
```

You may need to close the application, if it's already running, before Windows will permit you to <strike>delete</strike> rename the file.  I have been happily "follower free" for months since removing the program with no adverse effects.

Some coworkers have reported that yet *other* versions of the software will lose audio capability after deleting the file, so the instructions above have been modified to suggest *renaming* the file instead so it's easier to recover if you have a similar experience.

Answer (score 18):

### One time solution

You can close it by focusing it (clicking on it) and pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>.

### Permanent solutions

#### 1. Turning it off

On some HP laptops there is a setting for this in the B&O Control Panel. Check, whether you have [Show sound controls during VoIP calls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUF4x.png) option, and turn it off (picture taken from [William Price's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1519568/1197081)).

#### 2. Renaming AppFollower.exe

The B&O panel, that follows the window of video/audio calls is this program:

```
C:\Program Files\CONEXANT\Flow\AppFollower.exe
```

Rename it, so that it cannot start. Note: to be able to rename it, it may not be running. Later if Windows Update reinstalls the .exe, you may have to rename it again.

#### 3. Disabling the service

`AppFollower.exe` is started by the B&O tray icon. The B&O tray icon is started by a service. Disable that service, and you won't have the tray icon, the app follower, and even it may be faster to log in to Windows.

- Open Start Menu, type `Services`, and start the Services app.
- Type `cx` to scroll down in the list to `CxAudioSvc`. Open it (doubleclick).
- Press `Stop`.
- Set the `Startup type` popup to `Disabled`.
- Press `OK`.
- In the system tray rightclick the B&O icon, and select `Exit`, or restart the computer.

[image: Bang & Olufsen Tray Icon]

When Windows Update downloads a newer version of the CONEXANT driver, you will notice that the service is running again, so you have to repeat these steps.

#### 4. Editing the Options file

- Under `C:\Users\[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Packages\22094SynapticsIncorporate.BangOlufsenAudioControlP_qt57b6kdvhcfw\LocalCache\Local\Conexant\Flow` there is an `Options` file (no extension). The numbers in the path may differ!
- Change `FollowSkypeLync` to `False`.
- If the background process `Bang & Olufsen` is running, kill it or reboot the client. A restart of the `CxAudioSvc` service was not enough.